# Scrollable flex child with flex-grow 1

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a scrollable flex-child whose height is determined by its flex-grow property.

Example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.heading {
  background: #9D8189;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 2rem;
  min-height: 10rem;
}

.content {
  background: #FFE5D9;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding: 2rem;
  /* Makes it scrollable but breaks the flexbox layout */
  max-height: 40vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.box {
  background: #D8E2DC;
  padding: 7rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="heading">heading</div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="box">box1</div>
      <div class="box">box2</div>
      <div class="box">box3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

([*jsfiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/ymfL9owh/))

The layout consists of the flex-parent `.container` and two flex-children:

- `.heading`, that has a fixed height defined by `padding` and `min-height`, and
- `.content` that is supposed to take all the remaining after `.heading`  space. In order to achieve that, the first flex-child (`.heading`) has `flex: 0 0 auto` and the second flex-child (`.content`) has `flex: 1 0 auto`.

However, I also want `.content` to have scrollable content inside. For now, the only way I see I can do that is to force `.content` to have a somewhat fixed height (e.g. via `max-height`, as I did in the provided example by setting it to `40vh`). But while it makes it scrollable, it also breaks the flexbox layout, where `content`'s height is `parent` height minus `heading` height.

It seems that as soon as I specify `.content` height, it stops respecting the flexbox layout, which makes sense. But is there some other way to make it scrollable while retaining its height which is defined by flexbox layout?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`height:100%` requires a known  `height` from parent to be calculated , unless the element is `HTML` itself.
You need : `html, body, {height:100%}` so  `.container {height:100%}` as a meaning , `height` value will be inherited from `HTML` (browser's window) then  by `BODY` and finally `.container` .

`VH` can also be used instead `%` to make it simple.

`.container` should be set to `overflow:hidden` to allow children to scroll once reaching the limit of the parent.

Code sample :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;/* update */
  overflow:hidden;/* update */
}

.heading {
  background: #9D8189;
  /*flex: 0 0 auto; */
  padding: 2rem;
  min-height: 10rem;/* if needed */
}

.content {
  background: #FFE5D9;
  flex: 1 ;/* make it simple */
  padding: 2rem;
  overflow: auto;/* scroll if needed */
}

.box {
  background: #D8E2DC;
  padding: 7rem;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="heading">heading</div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="box">box1</div>
      <div class="box">box2</div>
      <div class="box">box3</div>
      <div class="box">box3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `min-height: 0` to .`content` class style and it should work as you expectm