# Scrollable flexbox with flex grow 1 and adapting the height of one flex-child to other

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

The question is 30% similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56093138/scrollable-flex-child-with-flex-grow-1), but mine is a different layout.

In the code snippet, I have two divs, `.left` and `.right`, each of them are children of `.outer` (which is a flexbox). The `.right` has a `.scrollable` that has `overflow-y: auto` for when its content overflows.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
.outer {
  background: pink;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.left {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 80px;
}

.right {
  background: skyblue;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.static {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.scrollable {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow-y: auto;
  gap: 2px;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  
  flex: 1;
}

.item {
  background: white;
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="left">
    Left Area
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="static">
      Static
    </div>
    <div class="scrollable">
      <div class="item">
        Item
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Item
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Item
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Item
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Item
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Item
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Item
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Item
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem I face is:

1. The `.scrollable` has `flex: 1` so that it can take up remaining space in its parent flexbox. But this way, scrollbars never appear, because the content inside it never overflows.
2. To make the `.scrollable` scrollable, I have to constraint the height, beyond which the scrollbars appear. But, I want the `.right` to have the same height as `.left` always, i.e. the `.left` and `.right` should have the same height.